# Dependency Property doesnt trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a problem with dependency properties. I have been searching quite a while for "how tos" but nothing could help me so far.

I need a Grid to change its background color when I drag something into it. Here is my code so far:

**VB**

```
Friend Shared ReadOnly isDragOverPropertyKey As DependencyPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("isDragOver", GetType(Boolean), _
                                                                                                      GetType(ucPageControl), _
                                                                                                      New PropertyMetadata(False))


Public Shared ReadOnly isDragOverProperty As DependencyProperty = isDragOverPropertyKey.DependencyProperty

Private _isDragOver As Boolean = True
Public Property isDragOver() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(isDragOverProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(isDragOverProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub Grid_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As Windows.DragEventArgs)
    isDragOver = True
End Sub


Private Sub Grid_DragLeave(sender As Object, e As Windows.DragEventArgs)
    isDragOver = False
End Sub
```

**XAML**

```
 <Grid Margin="0,0,216,63" DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" DragLeave="Grid_DragLeave" MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave_1" AllowDrop="True" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Elements:ucPageControl.isDragOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Elements:ucPageControl.isDragOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Somehow my Grid doesnt realize when my property changes. Anyone here to help?

Comment: You shouldn't call SetValue with the read-only `isDragOverProperty`. Try `SetValue(isDragOverPropertyKey, value)` instead. Besides that, remove the private `_isDragOver` field. It isn't used.

Comment: The reason why your solution does not work as you'd expect is that your property is set on your (presumably) `UserControl` (the class in which it is defined), yet your triggers expect it to be set on the `Grid` (which never happens). You might want to consider using [attached dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) as opposed to the regular one. Otherwise, you should use `DataTrigger` instead of `Trigger`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that inherites Grid and contains dependancy property. And use it in xaml.

```
<controls:MyGrid Margin="0,0,216,63" DragEnter="Grid_DragEnter" DragLeave="Grid_DragLeave" MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter_1" MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave_1" AllowDrop="True" >
    <controls:MyGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </controls:MyGrid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:MyGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="controls:MyGrid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsDragOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsDragOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </controls:MyGrid.Style> 
</controls:MyGrid>
```

Comment: Could you please add the c# code for the class, to clarify?